# Crash when i try to update TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do an calculator app (school project), so i need a TextView for displaying the numbers. Because it's my first java project i wanted for the beginning to make a counter which displays how many times the button was clicked(just to learn how to work with TextViews). My problem is that after the first update of the TextView(when it is displaying "1") when i press the button for the second time it gives me a crash.

My code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Integer number = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no1);

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zeroB);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            number++;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no1);
            tv.setText(number.toString());
        }
    });
}
...
```

**content_main.xml**

```
    ...
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/no1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:editable="true" />
     ...
```

Comment: why are you calling setContentView inside the listener and why are you inialising the TextView inside the listener?

Comment: @helldawg13 - I think OP is trying to get the textview to set its text.

Comment: Armin Raminfar The error : "Unfortunately, Base Calculator has stopped."
@helldawg13 well how can i use the textview if don't call it inside the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Integer number = 0;
//i would use this instead of the above
private int number = 0;
private TextView tv;
private ImageButton button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no1);
    button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zeroB);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            number++;
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        }
    });
}
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't tv be final or a field? You can't access it within the scope of the listener.

Comment: @helldawg13 Should I make the textfield global, because i can't acces it inside the onClick function ?